# JSONObject not a String Error

Tags: java, json

```
    {
  "query": {
    "count": 1,
    "created": "2015-07-28T05:19:01Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "results": {
      "quote": {
        "symbol": "GITANJALI.NS",
        "Ask": null,
        "AverageDailyVolume": null,
        "Bid": null,
        "AskRealtime": null,
        "BidRealtime": null,
        "BookValue": null,
        "Change_PercentChange": null,
        "Change": null,
        "Commission": null,
        "Currency": null,
        "ChangeRealtime": null,
        "AfterHoursChangeRealtime": null,
        "DividendShare": null,
        "LastTradeDate": null,
        "TradeDate": null,
        "EarningsShare": "9.73",
        "ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid": null,
        "EPSEstimateCurrentYear": null,
        "EPSEstimateNextYear": null,
        "EPSEstimateNextQuarter": null,
        "DaysLow": null,
        "DaysHigh": null,
        "YearLow": null,
        "YearHigh": null,
        "HoldingsGainPercent": null,
        "AnnualizedGain": null,
        "HoldingsGain": null,
        "HoldingsGainPercentRealtime": null,
        "HoldingsGainRealtime": null,
        "MoreInfo": null,
        "OrderBookRealtime": null,
        "MarketCapitalization": null,
        "MarketCapRealtime": null,
        "EBITDA": null,
        "ChangeFromYearLow": null,
        "PercentChangeFromYearLow": null,
        "LastTradeRealtimeWithTime": null,
        "ChangePercentRealtime": null,
        "ChangeFromYearHigh": null,
        "PercebtChangeFromYearHigh": null,
        "LastTradeWithTime": null,
        "LastTradePriceOnly": null,
        "HighLimit": null,
        "LowLimit": null,
        "DaysRange": null,
        "DaysRangeRealtime": null,
        "FiftydayMovingAverage": null,
        "TwoHundreddayMovingAverage": null,
        "ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": null,
        "PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": null,
        "ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": null,
        "PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": null,
        "Name": null,
        "Notes": null,
        "Open": null,
        "PreviousClose": null,
        "PricePaid": null,
        "ChangeinPercent": null,
        "PriceSales": null,
        "PriceBook": null,
        "ExDividendDate": null,
        "PERatio": null,
        "DividendPayDate": null,
        "PERatioRealtime": null,
        "PEGRatio": null,
        "PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear": null,
        "PriceEPSEstimateNextYear": null,
        "Symbol": "GITANJALI.NS",
        "SharesOwned": null,
        "ShortRatio": null,
        "LastTradeTime": null,
        "TickerTrend": null,
        "OneyrTargetPrice": null,
        "Volume": null,
        "HoldingsValue": null,
        "HoldingsValueRealtime": null,
        "YearRange": null,
        "DaysValueChange": null,
        "DaysValueChangeRealtime": null,
        "StockExchange": null,
        "DividendYield": null,
        "PercentChange": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Json I'm getting and I'm trying to get **MarketCapitalization** out of this using:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

by doing following operation:

```
String marketCap = obj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results")
                .getJSONObject("quote").getString("MarketCapitalization");
```

but I'm getting following error

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["MarketCapitalization"] not a string.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:658)
    at com.mobileforce.YahooClient.prepareReadCompany(YahooClient.java:136)
    at com.mobileforce.YahooClient.read(YahooClient.java:82)
    at com.mobileforce.YahooClient.handleApi(YahooClient.java:42)
    at com.mobileforce.YahooServlet.doPost(YahooServlet.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Note: If in case MarketCapitalization has some value then the above is working completely fine. The problem is occurring only when it is null**

Answer (score 7):

Use optString() to get the value if it exists otherwise null or a default value you defined:

```
.optString("MarketCapitalization", "defaultValue");
```

See [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 5):

Try doing some proactive check for `null` before use, E.g. :

```
jsonObj.isNull("MarketCapitalization"){

//do something

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Helped me out in saving details with optional values...One upvote from me!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `getObject()` instead of `getString()`, then check for null. But that's obviously not a strong point of the library you are using...

Comment: No, It's not working now i'm getting the following error  org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["MarketCapitalization"] is not a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

First check wheather the value of key "MarketCapitalization" is null or not
if not null the do your work

```
    JSONObject quoteJson = obj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results")
            .getJSONObject("quote");
    if(quoteJson.get("MarketCapitalization")!=null)
    {
        //do your work
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject receives an array for each data field, takes this data and transfers it to another variable, such as an array or string using the field name as a reference, such as 'value', 'name' and etc... If null, transfer a value in white to avoid mistakes. I do like this...

```
String value; 

if(jsonObject.get("name").toString().equals("null")) {
  value = ""; 
}else {
  value = jsonObject.getString("name"); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.