# Why does minify cause error "JSONObject["rewards"] not a string"?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, minify, android-r8

Somehow from one App release into another the internals of org.json library broke. It could no longer read the contents of a key as a string. Here is an example of the code that used to work and is breaking when minify/R8/proguard is enabled.

```
    try {
        parseJson("{\"rewards\":[{\"amount\":1,\"name\":\"Add Audio\"}]}");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("TEST", "Error parsing rewarded currencies JSON header!!!", e);
    }
    
    private void parseJson(@NonNull String rewardedCurrencies) throws JSONException {
        final Map<String, String> rewardsMap = jsonStringToMap(rewardedCurrencies);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : rewardsMap.entrySet()) {
            Log.e("TEST", entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> jsonStringToMap(String jsonParams) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, String> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonParams)) return jsonMap;

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonParams).nextValue();
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

        Log.e("TEST", "jsonStringToMap() -> jsonObject: "+jsonObject.toString());

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            Log.e("TEST", "jsonStringToMap() -> key: "+key);
            jsonMap.put(key, jsonObject.getString(key));
        }

        return jsonMap;
    }
```

**Log output with failure:**

```
jsonStringToMap() -> jsonObject: {"rewards":[{"amount":1,"name":"Add Audio"}]}
jsonStringToMap() -> key: rewards
Error parsing rewarded currencies JSON header!!!
    j.b.b: JSONObject["rewards"] not a string.
        at j.b.d.getString(SourceFile:4)
```

So what changed on the project since the last working App release?

> targetSdkVersion 28 -> 29
>
> sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 -> JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>
> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0' -> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
>
> distributionUrl ->
> gradle-6.1.1-all.zip -> gradle-6.5-all.zip

The fix was to apply a new line to the proguard script.

> -keep class org.json.** { *; }

And now I'm worried. Why do I need to apply this to proguard? Are there other internal libraries potentially breaking? I can't seem to figure out what has caused this and if it's a potential big issue?

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace and tell us on which line this happens?

Comment: I'm also having trouble finding out what the expected output of your program is. Can you explain what the function does? Maybe that will point to the underlying issue

Comment: @JensV thanks for reminder! Forgot to add the logs.

Comment: The Exception name is missing from the stacktrace

Comment: Something came just to mind: Can you take a look at your dependencies? There might be a library providing `org.json` which you are using instead of the standard library and then gets proguarded away...

Comment: Updated my answer with new info

Comment: Updated it again, found the root cause definitely now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reference I could find to the Exception text in your error log is from here: [JSONObject not a String Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31668023/2232127)

I couldn't find a code-path from the Android org.json implementation that would lead to that Exception. This means that [`org.json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) is somehow getting packaged into your App. This would also mean that it's not a standard library problem as you've feared.

Further reinforcing that point: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java#L849-L864

This explains your issue exactly. The implementation of `JSONObject#getString(String key)` differs to the Android implementation. You can only read String values of an Object this way. Any other value will be rejected and cause the Exception. Since you are reading a `JSONArray` this will not work.

My example below will fix this issue whether you're using the Android Standard Library or the pulled dependency.

The reason why it works without ProGuard is that Androids org.json is already provided by the System. When minifying, it will rename the dependency org.json package and thus force you to use it.

I would recommend getting rid of the `org.json` dependency. Alternatively write code that works with both... You may want to switch to `Gson` or `Jackson` anyways since it's a lot easier to use.

```
    public static Map<String, String> jsonStringToMap(String jsonParams) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, String> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonParams)) return jsonMap;

        // Use JSONObject constructor
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonParams);

        Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

        Log.e("TEST", "jsonStringToMap() -> jsonObject: " + jsonObject.toString());

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Log.e("TEST", "jsonStringToMap() -> key: " + key);
            // Type safe way to get the String value of any type within the key
            // Probably needs to handle null values correctly
            jsonMap.put(key, String.valueOf(jsonObject.get(key)));
        }

        return jsonMap;
    }
```

Comment: You rock! It totally makes sense. I'll do some investigation and circle back with my findings. Thank you JensV! :)

Comment: Turns out a 3rd party library included the org.json library somehow. I can't confirm exactly how they managed to do it but removing their library resolved the problem. Thanks again for helping out!

Comment: Hi @JensV
your answer worked perfectly.

can i ask you a further question please.

how did you manage to do find out this :
no code-path from the Android org.json implementation to the exception

. how did you find out that there is no code path from android org.json implementation ?
please let me know.

Comment: @mrtechmaker it's been a few years, but I think I just read the Android source code and figured that either it doesn't throw that exception or the provided code would not trigger that exception. I'm pretty sure I also looked at the git history to see if anything had changed.

Answer (score 1):

This issue could happen because when you apply r8 shrinker to your Android app, it renames some of the internal fields and method defined in the class. If these methods/fields are references else where in the code, then it would have undefined/ unexpected behavior. To fix this Try adding this rule in your proguard file and will prevent R8 from renaming publically referenced fields and methods

`-keep class org.json.** { *; }`

Comment: I think the question is more of a "why does this happens", his proguard rule already works

Comment: What's interesting is that this rule actually doesn't fix it. But the more aggressive one -keep class org.json.** { *; } does fix the issue.

Comment: This rule would actually prevent renaming all class/method/fields under org.json package.

Comment: What's even more interesting is that I can't get it to break in a test project with R8 enabled

Comment: Also try with the JSONObject constructor to parse the json string instead of using tokener.